# IE9 adding extra tags

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have some code, IE9 is adding extra tags to it.

```
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                            <div class="offerings">
                                                            <h4>Title</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                                                   <h4>Title</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </h4></div><h4>
                    </h4></div><h4>
                </h4></div><h4>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                            <h4>Title:</h4>
                            </div></div></div></h4><div class="row"><div class="feature crosshair-icon"><div class="offerings"><h4>Title</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </h4></div><h4>
                    </h4></div><h4>

                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                            <h4>Title:</h4>
                            </div></div></h4><div class="feature crosshair-icon"><div class="offerings"><h4>Title</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Original code:

```
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                            <h4>Title:</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                            <h4>Title:</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                            <h4>Title:</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feature crosshair-icon">
                        <div class="offerings">
                            <h4>Title:</h4>
                           <ul>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                                <li>List</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

For example the following should not be there:

```
                </h4></div><h4>
            </h4></div><h4>
        </h4></div><h4>
```

I'm not sure why it would be doing this? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: can you show the original code and what IE makes of it?

Comment: @SLaks There's nothing that "makes no sense" about this snippet of code. Perhaps the original code will clear it up.